# How impermeable of a seal should a tub drain gasket provide?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub

Regarding the gasket that sits between the underside of a tub, and the female-threaded PVC drain elbow: ***how leak-proof should it be?***  Under the best conditions that I've been able to achieve, mine *glistens* while draining -- especially from a full tub -- but doesn't seem to ever out-right drip.  And that is with a fresh new gasket.  I wonder about years from now when it has become more rigid from out-gassing, hard water deposits, and bathtub cleaning agents.

BACKGROUND:

I recently installed a new tub, on a 3-to-4 inch mortar bed as required by the tub's manufacturer.  The tub manufacturer also provided compatible hardware, such as the threaded drain insert (which I think is perhaps called a "shoe"?) and the stopper mechanism that it houses.

The documentation that came with the threaded drain insert recommended the use of silicone sealant instead of plumbers putty, when torquing it down through the tub's drain hole into the threaded waste elbow.  This sounded fine by me, because I've had bad experiences with plumbers putty before.

To get a perfect seal (between tub and drain insert) with that silicone sealant, I had to torque it down until the sealant was uniformly smooshed.  Only then would the stopped tub not leak when full of water.

But that degree of tightening caused another problem: sure, now my full tub didn't leak when stopped.  But it did then leak when draining.

Here's what I think was happening:  either my licensed plumber didn't cement the waste elbow *perfectly* level, or the underside of the acrylic & fiberglass tub isn't *perfectly* uniform, so torquing the drain insert down to stop leaks when the drain is closed, causes the gasket under the tub to distort.  Thus when you have 2 feet of head pressure above that gasket, the water drains forcefully enough that it can get past the distorted gasket and start pooling on the floor.

After a few reattempts I abandoned the silicone, and begrudgingly switched to plumbers putty.  This allowed me to achieve a stopped seal with less tightening.  And, things appeared to remain watertight also while draining.   Sounds like a win.

Except: the gasket does at least glisten at the interfaces while draining. Not enough moisture appears to ever coalesce into a droplet, but... yeah.

Is this copacetic?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the glistering is not condensation from the air instead of water getting past the seal?  Seal leaks are usually drippy at least, but could try tightening another half turn.

Comment: At the time of the above picture, house was ~70F, and tub was filled with warm water.  Under those circumstances I can't see how that gasket could be chilled enough that it would condensate moisture out of my air-conditioned air.  EDIT: also the moistening happens only during draining.

Comment: Might just need another 1/4 or 1/2 turn to seal it completely, unless some damage/dirt in the sealing surfaces.

Comment: Yeah maybe, but thinking that w/ the silicone is what got me into trouble the first time.

Comment: IME putty only works for locations where the two surfaces being sealed do not rotate relative to each other, e.g. a kitchen sink drain and disposal where you have a bigass nut *below* the sink.  In a situation where you have to screw the drain down and the flange rotates against the sink/vessel, putty tends to break up.

Comment: I'd contact the tub manufacturer for guidance.